# Hide Shipping method from cart page in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I want to hide or remove the Shipping Method from cart page.
The reason to hide is we are giving free delivery on order above 15 pound.
but since magento save the users shipping method in session it show the shipping and handling charge as 3 pound even though the order amount is greater than 15 pound (should be Free delivery).

Or way to unset shipping method from session.

Please refer the image.

[image: Remove shipping from Cart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unset current shipping method

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
$shippingMethod = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
if($shippingMethod){
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod(null);  //setting method to null
    $quote->save(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Second option is best .

Unset current shipping method using below code at Cart page:

```
if($shippingMethod=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
            ->getShippingMethod()){
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
            ->unsetShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
}
```

Comment: i have applied the code in `/template/checkout/cart.phtml` but shipping still shows up.

Comment: thank you @amit-bera for pointing me to right direction. I have got the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Login to adminpanel,

admin > system > configuration > sales > shipping methods > select your desire method here and put enabled as Yes. And remaining all select enable as No.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not what i want as i have 3 method Free( for 15 pound+) Flat rate(for < 15 pound) and Next  Day delivery(optional). and i want free/Flat rate(any one depending on order amount) and Next day delivery together.